# How view controller talks to another view controller in MVC mode?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

Suppose I have two MVCs, how the two communicate? As I know it should be be done by the vc talks another vc. Is that correct? How to implement it? Any sample code on it? Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this introduction to iOS lecture from Stratford - it gives you a good base and he is an absolutely brilliant lecturer.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipN6ksUgpZo

Comment: Thanks so much. It is classic! I have learned it by can't position the time.